# extract and use type parameters in higher kinded types?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Say I have a class that takes a higher kinded type, and I'm trying to write something like this:

```
class Foo[T[U]](thing: T[U]) {
  def someMethodThatUsesU(arg: U): U = ???
}
```

This fails to compile, because the compiler doesn't recognize the symbol `U`. How come? Is there another way to write this without doing something like `class Foo[U, T[U]]`?

Some context: this is a simplified example of the problem. Ultimately, I'd like to write something like this:

```
trait SomeTrait[T]

class SomeClass[T[U] <: SomeTrait[U]](arg: T[U]) {
  def somethingWithU(arg: U): U = ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works for my use-case quite well. Simply assign that type to a type member and use type projection:

```
trait SomeTrait[T] {
  type A = T
}

class SomeClass[T <: SomeTrait[_]] {
  def someMethod(arg: T#A): T#A
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`T[U]` isn't really a higher-kinded type if you care what `U` is. It' just a plain old type. A higher-kinded type would be if your class or method were parameterized by something's type constructor alone, e.g. `Option` or `List`.

`class[T[U]](...)` fails to compile because you're trying to use two type parameters, but only declare `T`. There is no way to declare two type parameters in that way. The only good option you have is declaring `T` to be higher-kinded, with a second type parameter `U` that varies independently:

```
class Foo[T[_], U](thing: T[U]) {
  def someMethodThatUsesU(arg: U): U = ???
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying what higher-kinded types are. Yeah, this would work, although it's basically what I was originally trying to avoid :(